# Making a Modal Window in CMS no css external page. Can't use Pseudo-class. Can't use <style> tag

Tags: javascript, magento-1.7, pseudo-class

I am using a CMS page in Magento 1.7. The wysiwyg editor strips style tags but not  tags. I do not have access to the wysiwyg .js to add the style tag. I also don't have access to adding an external css page or javascript page.

I want to make a modal window using HTML and Javascript.  I can use a style attribute `<div style="...">` but when I do this, I cannot use a pseudo-class like :target.

Basically what I would like to do is find a work around so I don't use this:

```
<style>.modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;</style>
```

Is there anything that I can do other than CSS style tag to get this to work?
I would like to have text linked to a modal window that opens up to an image. Do you know of another way of doing this without pseudo classes?